# .htaccess tricks for multi-language website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now, I have a website that uses two languages (French and English).

The way it currently works is that if someone goes to `mysite.com/folder/file.php` for example, `file.php` is simply a script that figures out which language to use, gets it's own path and filename (`file.php`) and serves up `mysite.com/en/folder/file.php` (if the language is English). However, what shows up in the URL is still `mysite.com/folder/file.php`.

For any folder and any file, the same script is used. If I want to add a new file, I have to add the file to the folder the user types into the browser as well to the `en` and `fr` folders.

Could I do some `.htaccess` tricks so that whatever URL is typed, one `.php` file gets opened, checks the language and the folder/file which is requested, and then serves up the correct language file?

Here's the php file that is served up for any files in the URL.

```
<?php 

// Get current document path which is mirrored in the language folders
$docpath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// Get current document name (Used when switching languages so that the same
current page is shown when language is changed)
$docname = GetDocName();

//call up lang.php which handles display of appropriate language webpage.
//lang.php uses $docpath and $docname to give out the proper $langfile.
//$docpath/$docname is mirrored in the /lang/en and /lang/fr folders
$langfile = GetDocRoot()."/lang/lang.php";
include("$langfile"); //Call up the proper language file to display

function GetDocRoot()
{
 $temp = getenv("SCRIPT_NAME");
 $localpath=realpath(basename(getenv("SCRIPT_NAME")));
 $localpath=str_replace("\\","/",$localpath);
 $docroot=substr($localpath,0, strpos($localpath,$temp));
 return $docroot;
}

function GetDocName()
{
$currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
$dn = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
return $dn;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to have the root of the site (/index.php) figure out the preferred language and then redirect to a URL containing the language code.  If your files are then separated by language on disk they can be requested directly.

Or you can add a simple regex in .htaccess or your host setup to grab the language out of the requested URL and send all similar requests to one file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/folder/file.php$ /folder/file.php?lang=$1
```

Then reference `$_GET['lang']` in PHP to see which language was requested.  You'll probably want to expand this to be more generalized for all similar files on the site, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.+)\.php$ /$2.php?lang=$1
```